# Create an ItemGroup of Paths, where the paths contains shortcuts(.lnk)

Tags: msbuild

I want to create an ItemGroup of shortcuts, which resolve to actual target when that item is used in copy task.

For an instance:

if a shortcut file **MyShortcut.lnk** points to **C:\MyFolder\SomeotherFolder** and say this shortcut lies in **C:\MyshortcutsFolder** ,now I want to create an Item Group of paths having the above .lnk file

i.e

```
<ItemGroup>
    <MyPath Include="C:\MySortcutFolder\MyShortcut\**\*.cs">
</ItemGroup>
```

So now "MyPath" should be included with all cs files in **C:\MyFolder\SomeotherFolder**.

I don't If had to implement this in an other way or am doing something wrong while including, Please help!

Comment: This can only be done if you create a custom task that can parse the `.lnk` file. There is no support in MsBuild to do this out of the box.

Comment: You might consider using a Symlink/Junction instead of a .lnk file http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that Jesse! Yup I will probably write a custom task as Junction doesn't work on remote shares.